Setting symbol layers in QGIS
I am using QGIS 3.2.
I have read all of the online documentation and follow-alongs, and I still cannot set symbol layers.
My screen looks like this:

It should show all of the styled layers:

I have saved the symbols and styles, and still nothing seems to help.

The screenshot from the documentation shows a categorized layer, which contains several symbologies, each with their own symbol levels.
